# Delete Entries in File if the Same Entry Exists in a Master File

Tags: shell-script, scripting, json

I have a JSON master config file whose value may be overwritten by a specific account's config file (also in JSON). The Master file has this structure:

```
{
    "section1Configs": {
        "setting01": true,
        "setting02": true,
        "setting03": false
    },
    section2Configs: {
        "setting01": true,
        "setting02": true,
        "setting03": false
    },
    section3Configs: {
        "setting01": true,
        "setting02": true,
        "setting03": false
    },
    section4Configs: {
        "setting01": true,
        "setting02": true,
        "setting03": false
    }
}
```

The config file for a specific account may look like this:

```
{
    "section1Configs": {
        "setting01": true,
        "setting02": true,
        "setting03": true
    },
    section2Configs: {
        "setting01": false,
        "setting02": true,
        "setting03": false
    },
    section3Configs: {
        "setting01": true,
        "setting02": false,
        "setting03": false
    },
    section4Configs: {
        "setting01": true,
        "setting02": true,
        "setting03": false
    }
}
```

Note that they are identical except certain values (section01Config.setting03, section02Config.setting01, and section03Config.setting02) are different. Note also that the entire section4Configs block is the same in both files.

The ones that are the same are not needed since the application loads both and overwrites the Master file with the ones that are different in the account config.

What I would like to do is have a script that iterates through a directory of such account files and deletes the entry in each file that are the same key and value as the Master file. From this example I would end up with a file like this:

```
{
    section1Configs: {
        setting03: true
    },
    section2Configs: {
        setting01: false
    },
    section3Configs: {
        setting02: false
    }
}
```

There are over 200 account config files and doing this manually will take a lifetime. Any help is greatly appreciated!

------ EDIT -------

I tried to keep the question simple but I think a missing detail will have an impact on the answer.

The account and config JSON file consist of sections and their corresponding settings. This means that the JSON is one level deeper than what's mentioned above:

```
{
    "section1Configs": {
        "level1Settings": {
            "section01Lev01_01": true,
            "section01Lev01_012": true,
            "section01Lev01_02": true
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I copied your bottom thing into two files.

File 1:

```
{
    "section1Configs": {
        "level1Settings": {
            "section01Lev01_01": true,
            "section01Lev01_012": true,
            "section01Lev01_02": true
        }
    }
}
```

And File 2...

```
{
    "section1Configs": {
        "level1Settings": {
            "section01Lev01_01": true,
            "section01Lev01_012": false,
            "section01Lev01_02": true
        }
    }
}
```

They only differ on the *`Level01_012`* line.

Then I did:

```sh
grep -Ev '[{}]|^$' file1 | grep -Fxvf- file2
```

---

```
{
    "section1Configs": {
        "level1Settings": {
            "section01Lev01_012": false,
        }
    }
}
```

That command is broken down as follows:

1. `grep -Ev '[{}]|^$' file1`

   - Here we ask `grep` to please print every line in *`file1`* which does not match either a `{` character or a `}` character, but it must match at least *one* character.
   - Its output looks like:

     ```
             "section01Lev01_01": true,
             "section01Lev01_012": true,
             "section01Lev01_02": true
     ```
2. `grep -Fxvf- file2`

   - That is read by this second `grep` which interprets its `-` stdin input pattern `-f`ile as a `-F`ixed-string pattern `-x` entire-line match which it should -`v` *not* print to output. And so this second `grep` prints every line in file2 which doesn't exactly match the true/false lines in file1.

---

Now if your `grep` does not understand `-` as stdin we have a few options:

```
grep -Ev '[{}]|^$' file1 | grep -Fxvf /dev/fd/0 file2
```

...will work on most systems. A similar option is to use `/dev/stdin`, which is also pretty likely to work, if a little less so.

There is also a shell-specific implementation know as *process-substitution* which works in just about exactly the same way...

```
grep -Fxvf <(grep -Ev '[{}]|^$' file1) file2
```

...which may or may not work for you depending on your shell.

Another possibility is...

```
grep -Fxv "$(grep -Ev '[{}]|^$' file1)" file2
```

...which may or may not work for you depending on how large the output of the command-subbed `grep` is.

Try a few and probably you'll find one that works for you.

Comment: the first part of this command works "grep -Ev '[{}]|^$' file1" but the other part "grep -Fxvf- file2" produces the following error: grep: -: No such file or directory. Running the first command with the second file works too so I'm not sure why it says "No such file..."

Comment: Ok. So I'll change it. Most `grep`s refer to `-` as stdin. Some do not. And so we can do something else.

Comment: @vdiaz1130 - please see the edit I have just made. It should cover most bases.

Comment: This works. Thanks! Just needs a little bit more work to get it to do what I need. Basically iterate through a directory of files. Also need to remove the comma at the end of this example. {
    "section1Configs": {
        "level1Settings": {
            "section01Lev01_02": false,
        }
    }
} Thanks!

Comment: @vdiaz130 - I don't know what this last thing means.

Comment: Using the command you provided with the sample files from above, the JSON retains a comma after the last entry. Some browsers will not process that correctly so it needs to be removed. Also, I need to run this command on many JSON files within a specific directory so it needs to pull the files recursively and execute the command you provided. This is a really good starting point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be better to use tools specialized for json like **jq** or **jshon**?
But if you'd like it can be done with `paste` and `sed`

```
paste config master | sed '/[{}]/! {/\(.\+\)\t\1/d;};s/\t.*//'
```

or `awk`

```
awk '{getline a < "master"} /[{}]/ || $0 != a' config
```

for each line in config-file gets corresponding(by number) row from master-file into variable `a` and if line consist `{`or`}` or not the same with ones from master-file print it.
Result:

```
{
    "section1Configs": {
        "setting03": true
    },
    section2Configs: {
        "setting01": false,
    },
    section3Configs: {
        "setting02": false,
    },
    section4Configs: {
    }
}
```

Comment: paste acct.json master.json | sed '/[{}]/! {/\(.\+\)\t\1/d};s/\t.*//' produces the following error: sed: 1: "/[{}]/! {/\(.\+\)\t\1/d ...": extra characters at the end of d command

Comment: Can you explain the awk command? I think this is working but the JSON object can be another level deep like `{
    "section1Configs": {
        "level1Settings":{
            "section01Lev01_01": true,
            "section01Lev01_012": true,
            "section01Lev01_02": true
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @vdiaz1130 1) some `sed` implementations require `;`before`}` 2)added

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out elsewhere on this page, a robust and efficient way to solve the problem is to use a JSON-aware tool such as [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).  The following provides a solution to the original problem; it can easily be adapted to solve variants.

(1) Put the following in a file, say minusConfig.jq:

```
def minus(o1;o2):
  o1 | with_entries( select(o2[.key] != .value) );

def minusConfig(o1;o2):
  reduce (o1|keys)[] as $key ({};
    minus( o1[$key] ; o2[$key]) as $v
    | if $v == {} then . else . + {($key): $v} end );

minusConfig($user; $master)
```

(2) Assuming the master and user config files are master.json and user.json respectively,

```
$ jq -n --arg master master.json --arg user user.json -f minusConfig.jq
```

produces:

```
{
  "section1Configs": {
    "setting03": true
  },
  "section2Configs": {
    "setting01": false
  },
  "section3Configs": {
    "setting02": false
  }
}
```